# Javascript error alert message fired before call to NewStatement is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tin-can-api

I have the following Javascript code contained on the click event of an upload button where I want to record an xAPI statement. I have put a breakpoint on my Admin/NewStatement method and although it is hitting it the page is always displaying the error message even before I have stepped through the breakpoint. Why is this failing all the time?

```
var postData = {
  'userID': 1,
  'verbID': 26,
  'objectID':1
};

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/Admin/NewStatement",
  data: postData,
  success: function (data) {
    var json = data;
    alert("THIS IS MY JSON" + json);
    //tincan.sendStatement(json);
  },
  error: function (error) {
    alert("An Error has occurred during the Creation of this xAPI Statement");
    alert(error);                
  }
});
```

I have the following method at Admin/NewStatement

```
public string NewStatement(int userID, int verbID, int objectID)
    { 
        string result;
        result = avm.AddStatement(userID, verbID, objectID);
        return result;
    }
```

avm.AddStatement refers to my ViewModel code:

```
public string AddStatement(int userID, int verbID, int objectID)
    {
        Actor actor = actorRepository.Get(a => a.UserID == userID).FirstOrDefault();
        Verb verb = verbRepository.Get(v => v.VerbID == verbID).FirstOrDefault();
        StatementObject statementObject = statementObjectRepository.Get(o => o.StatementObjectID == objectID).FirstOrDefault();

        Statement newStatement = new Statement();
        newStatement.id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        newStatement.ActorID = actor.ActorID;
        newStatement.VerbID = verb.VerbID;
        newStatement.StatementObjectID = statementObject.StatementObjectID;

        this.statementRepository.Add(newStatement);
        this.statementRepository.SaveChanges();

        JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jss.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newStatement);
        return json.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting in console for the ajax request?

Comment: is your url `/Admin/NewStatement` valid?

Comment: yes /Admin/NewStatement is valid

Comment: Are you making a cross-domain request?

Comment: @Ziggy Doesn't look like it assuming the code they've posted is what they're actually running.

Comment: No I am calling this from /Admin/Index

Comment: The `error` parameter should be an object with a member `status` and `statusText`. Could you call `alert(error.status+" / "+error.statusText)` in your error function, please?